# How can I cast a JSONObject to a custom Java class?

Tags: java, json-simple

In Java ([using json-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)) I have successfully parsed a JSON string which was created in JavaScript using JSON.stringify.  It looks like this:

```
{"teq":14567,"ver":1,"rev":1234,"cop":15678}
```

This string is storing the state of a custom JavaScript object which I now wish to re-constitute as a pure Java class.  Its not going well - first foray into Java coming from a C# background.    :-p

The object is currently in the form of a org.json.simple.JSONObject since that is what json-simple made from the JSONParser.parse() operation.

**How can I cast this JSONObject to my new Java class?** (the definition of which is below...)

```
public class MyCustomJSObject {
    public int teq;
    public int ver;
    public int rev;
    public int cop;
}
```

Comment: You might want to look into Jackson.

Comment: I've heard a lot about it but chose json-simple since the library was thinner.  Maybe thinner is not so good?

Comment: Thinner means you have to do more yourself, such as mapping your JSON to a class.

Comment: @GeekStocks or google's gson

Answer (score 23, accepted):

use jackson library

```
    //create ObjectMapper instance
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    //convert json string to object
    Employee emp = objectMapper.readValue(jsonData, Employee.class);
```

Comment: I think user needs to convert using JSON-Simple

Comment: Yes, that is true, my requirement at the time was JSON-Simple. However, this question has become very popular and I have unaccepted my own answer and moved the checkmark here. I think the SO community benefits more by being guided to Jackson. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24236703/1884386

Answer (score 25):

Add dependency from https://github.com/google/gson and use it like

```
Gson gson= new Gson();
CustomPOJOClass obj = gson.fromJson(jsonObject.toString(),CustomPOJOClass.class);
```

Answer (score 8):

There are lot of libraries that does this. This is my suggestion. [Here](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) you can find the library

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
```

and then do,

```
Gson gson = new Gson();  
Student student = gson.fromJson(jsonStringGoesHere, Student.class);
```

Maven Dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks kindly for your reply.  I'm going to look into Gson if json-simple doesn't work out.

Answer (score 4):

### UPDATE 1/9/2018

Some years have passed since this (now popular) question was asked. While I still agree that json-simple was my need at the time, upon reflection I think the SO community is better served by having the "checkmark" next to the Jackson solution. I am un-accepting my own answer today; Jackson is pretty great!

---

I think that this decent json-simple library is the victim of poor documentation.  If  you don't use the JSONParser (go figure!) but instead use this JSONValue.parse() method, it all works out like so:

```
    //JSONParser parser = new JSONParser(); // DON'T USE THIS
    Object obj = JSONValue.parse("A JSON string - array of objects: [{},{}] - goes here");
    JSONArray arrFilings = (JSONArray)obj;
    System.out.println("We can print one this way...");
    System.out.println(arrFilings.get(5) + "\n");

    System.out.println("We can enumerate the whole array...");
    for(Object objFiling : arrFilings){
        System.out.println(objFiling);
    }
    System.out.println("\n");

    System.out.println("We can access object properties this way...");
    for(Object objFiling : arrFilings){
        JSONObject o = (JSONObject)objFiling; // MUST cast to access .get()
        MyJSObject.fyq = o.get("fyq");
    }
    System.out.println("\n");
```

Thanks to all those who posted.  Sticking with json-simple was the question and this is the only json-simple answer to-date. Jackson DOES look slick, and Amazon uses it in their SDK for Java too, sooo.... if its good enough for AWS....

Answer (score 3):

JSON string to Java Class ?
you can trying fastjson:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
    <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.41</version>
</dependency>
```

and using java code:

```
MyCustomJSObject object = JSON.parseObject(jsonString,MyCustomJSObject.class);
```

Comment: Neither Gson or Jackson worked for me, Fastjson works great.